# Android application crashed for proguard

Tags: android, proguard

In my android application , I've integrated Proguard . and exported an apk using export option of my eclipse. There was showing problem for my library files. All warning is ignored using bellow code.

```
 -dontwarn com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.**
 -dontwarn com.rabbitmq.client.**
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.**
 -dontwarn com.amazonaws.org.joda.time.**
 -dontwarn com.google.common.**
 -dontwarn com.rabbitmq.tools.json.**
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
 -dontwarn org.joda.time.**
```

But when I'm opening my installed apk. it's crushing . I don't know why?

Comment: There's way too little information in your question. You need to add any error messages that you get when running your app.

Comment: unfortunately error log is not showing for released apk.

Comment: does it run when you run from eclipse

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: My project is tested and it is working good without Proguard. I've also integrated Dexguard . it's also showing similar problem but in different pages. I'm sorry to say, I'm unable to find out any kinds of log message using release mode apk.

Comment: Finally I've found the log message after integrating Dexguard.
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lotd, PID: 21534
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.imaloader.ladzy.ImageLoaderCustome
at com.lotd.services.YoService.onCreate(:555)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)